QGIS graduated Symbology display Null Values
Working with QGIS 3.28.15 Firenze.
I was under the impression that QGIS was able to display "NULL" (empty) values when using graduated symbology. Is this not the case anymore?
I would like to make every "NULL" polygon transparent while the rest gets a color gradiant.
I cant use "0" as a stand in for the NULL value as "0" is the middle point of my gradiant and is displayed in white color.

I would adapt the answer from this question: How to symbolize features with NULL values in graduated symbology?
Instead of 0, use a number which is never going to be in range, e.g. 99999 or whatever isn't going to be present in your data. So within the symbology section of the layer properties, in the value field use expression:
case when "Column_Name" IS NULL then 99999 else "Column_Name" end

This will make your class boundaries lopsided, so untick 'Link Class Boundaries' found a bit further down the Symbology screen. Then manually amend the class boundaries with one that just contains NULL replacement value. You can then style that accordingly. Example below:

